# Request permissions on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-permissions, user-permissions

I'm trying to obtain multiple permissions, but if they are declined once, it never asks again.
without all the permisions the app won't work at all and you can't continue without accepting them all.

I have the following three lines in my manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
```

And this is how I am attempting to obtain those permissions:

```
 private void getPermissions() {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG}, 123);
            }
        }
```

Currently, this process works, but only once. After the permission is either declined or accepted and later removed, the app never prompts the user again. However, I want it to request permission every time I do not have the required permissions, and it needs to work on multiple versions of Android devices.

Comment: I recommend reading [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#handle-denial). If user denies a permission twice it's implied he doesn't want to grant it ever so dialog is forever suppressed. Before android 11 dialog had a checkbox that could be un-checked to keep asking but it's no longer the case.

Comment: well the app cannot work without it.

Comment: If you can't "gracefully degrade the experience" without having permissions there really isn't many options left. You can display an error and ask user to open app settings and grant missing permissions manually from there.

Comment: so i need to check if i have permission and if not let the user know he has to agree the permission and he needs to do it manually and i can't pop up the reqpermission again?

Comment: If i can't is there an option to open the app settings in the right place for the user?

Comment: You need to check the `shouldShowPermissionRationale` method and then redirect the user to the app's settings via `Intent` using `Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS`  intent action.

Comment: and will it ask for the permission again or will open the app settings in the right place? can u provide me the needed code?

Comment: yes no ??  any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As a start I will suggest to read the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#handle-denial).

That being said. This is my understanding when requesting permissions we have a ActivityResultContract.
Through this we have 3 cases:

1. The user grants the permission the first time it was requested. **GREAT**
2. The user denied the permission request. Now you can ask again - but first, **recommended to add**
   `shouldShowPermissionRationale`.
3. The user denied also the second time requested. Now it is recommended to display an error dialog to explain to the user the application won't be able to do it's work without the permission granted. and if the user decides to agree you can link the settings for change of permission. otherwise, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: ok i will  try rhank you.  Do you know how can i move the user to the correct place in the setting?

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null)); intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); startActivity(intent);`

Create an intent to the app info settings.
startActivity

Comment: Alr i will do it. Thank you so much